# Rotation matrix to Twist command

Tags: rotation, frames

I want to implement the J+RRT algorithm for which I need to use the Twist command to navigate the robot in Euclidean space.

First I calculate the difference in rotation matrices from the end-effector frame `T1` to the goal frame `T2` like so:

```
Tdiff * T1 = T2  // * T1^-1
Tdiff * T1 * T1^-1 = T2 * T1^-1
Tdiff = T2 * T1^-1
```

I am using the Frame separated as a rotation and translation.
Effectively this means that

```
T1^-1 = [R1^T -t1; 0 0 0 1]
```

RPY seems to be given in extrinsic x, y, z angles, which means that I need to convert it to intrinsic angles for the Twist command. This means that the RPY angles that I get from the `Tdiff` I would need to convert to my `R1` rotation frame. Is my thinking correct?

The code I'm using is this:

```
KDL::Rotation inv_src_rot = src.M.Inverse();
double x, y, z;
KDL::Rotation diff_rot = tgt.M * inv_src_rot;
diff_rot.GetRPY(x, y, z);
twist.rot = src.M * KDL::Vector(x, y, z);
```

This is the code for the RPY calculation:
https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics/blob/master/orocos_kdl/src/frames.cpp#L237-L260

EDIT: Right as I posted this I had another idea, which seems to me more correct.

If my goal is to go towards the goal rotation `tgt.M` in the end-effector reference frame `src.M`, it would make sense to calculate the RPY angles from the rotation

`src.M * tgt.M`,

since in this case the extrinsic frame has now become `src.M`. Now when I calculate RPY it will be the rotation `tgt.M` given in the `src.M` frame, if I'm not mistaken?

```
KDL::Rotation diff_rot = src.M * tgt.M;
diff_rot.GetRPY(x, y, z);
twist.rot = KDL::Vector(x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular velocities are strongly related to angle-axis description of a 3D rotation.

Instead of using RPY, just use the angle-axis vector (as in angle times unit axis) of the rotation error (R1.R2^T). Then the angular velocity to drive this vector to 0 is just proportional to the vector (e.g. this is a proportional velocity control in SO(3)).

Answer (score 1):

Your description is a bit confusing and I am unable to post a comment for clarification based on my reputation score, so I will try my best to help.

From your code, it looks like you only want to rotate the end-effector and not translate (is this true?).

Given that your end-effector is at orientation `src.M` in the world frame, and wants to go to a new orientation `tgt.M` in the end-effector frame, the new orientation in the world frame will be `src.M * tgt.M`, which is what you mention in your edit. But then, these will give you RPY *angles*, whereas Twist concerns with *angular velocities*. You need to implement a control that would vary your angular velocities (Twist) to get you to the required angle.